# HTML5 required attribute not working in Angular 2 project, installed using CLI

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am working on Angular 2 login page, when I try to validate input field with HTML 5 validate attribute required, it is not working, where as in the quick start project it works fine. Could any one explain why it is not working and how to resolve this issue ?

[Plunker link of my code](https://embed.plnkr.co/4Gy5z7Hz3x5h4XPU1zCl/) In Plunker, it validates but in my project its not working.

app.component.html code below,

```
<form class="login-form">
  <input type="text" name="usrname" placeholder="Username"  required/>

  <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password"  required>
  <input type="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: what you expected to see?? Please explain *why it is not working*? We can't by looking at this generic statement..

Comment: can you recreate you problem on plunker ?

Comment: have you added <!doctype html> to your index page?

Comment: My issue is HTML 5 required attribute is not working,  if the Angular 2 project is installed using CLI, but required attribute works fine if I  install using quick start. I want required attribute to work in CLI Angular 2 project. @ Pankaj Parkar

Comment: @ sri ram Yes in the index.html I have mentioned it as <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: do you have novalidate on the <form> tag? can you show the whole template and component?

Comment: @jmw5598  Nope just <form> tag with out any other attributes.

Comment: when using angulars built in validation you need to disable the browswers default validation by adding novalidate to the form tag <form novalidate>...</form>

Comment: Maybe you need `required="required"`

Comment: @ jmw5598 my template code below,  `<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    
    <form class="login-form" novalidate>
      <input type="text" name="usrname" placeholder="Username"  required="required">
      
      <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password"  required="required">
      <button type="submit">Submit </button>
    
    </form>
   
    <!--button (click)="hi()">Say hi</button-->
  </div>
</div>`  and Component code``

Comment: @ jmw5598   my component code `import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
`

Comment: @Gavin Bruce Just added and checked nope its not working by adding `required="required"`

Comment: you dont have angular form validation setup on your form.  check out the documenation.  It has a very basic example on how to apply form validation.  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgForm-directive.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As of version 4.0.0, Angular automatically adds "novalidate" to the form.  Change this new default behavior by using:

```
<form ngNativeValidate>...</form>
```

Github issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15531#issuecomment-289555359

Comment: anyone know why they do this by default?

Answer (score -1):

```
     <form class="login-form" novalidate> 
    <input type="text" name="usrname" placeholder="Username" required="required"> 
<input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" required="required"> 
<button type="submit">Submit </button> 
    </form>
```

remove novalidate from your form tag to enable html5 validation

```
<form class="login-form" >
```

If you use novalidate in your form tag, the validation wont occur as that's that the novalidate keyword is for when you don't want the default html5 validation and you want to implement your own validation means you have to use the novalidate otherwise you don't need it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion even after removing novalidate it does not worked. Actually I have added novalidate  after you asked. I will go through the links you have given..